# What is a Library that will let me Create/Emulate a Virtual Disk Drive in Windows using C#/.NET?

Tags: windows, library, c#, hard-disk

I want to use C# and .NET 5 to create a 'virtual' disk drive in Windows. This drive would show as a drive letter (M: etc) in e.g. windows file explorer and command prompt.

The actual handlers for listing files, reading or writing contents, etc. would be C# handler code I provide that does whatever I want (local disk access, cloud access, something else) to fulfill the requests.

I have found various articles explaining how to accomplish this kind of thing by creating a kernel-level driver with C++. I would really rather not.

The reason I ask this question here is because I feel about 95% certain I found a library for doing exactly this in C#, perhaps 2-6 years ago. I don't remember what it was called. And today I cannot find any trace of it either on the internet or on my local machine.

Comment: I think you at some point will need a kernel-mode driver to create the drive, as those are what manage the logical drives available. Moreover, drives persist more than the lifetime of your program, so I would doubt you can implement it fully in C#.